# make parent link active when child link is active

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Menu - fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xqwq6uL7/

```
.navigation-simple ul li a:hover,
.navigation-simple .active-nav,
.navigation-simple ul .dropdown>a,
.navigation-light ul li a:hover,.navigation-light .active-nav,
.navigation-light ul .dropdown>a {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #ff8833;
}
```

how can i set, in css, the parent links to be active when the child links are active?

Comment: Your demo isn't the best for demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it in pure CSS. You have to resort to JavaScript solution, e.g. `:has` selector implemented in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: do  you have an example in JS please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `.active-nav` is the `<a>` element.

You could move the class `active-nav` to the `<li>` element and select both:

```
.navigation-simple .active-nav, .navigation-simple .active-nav a { }
```

And in case of the `:hover`:

```
.navigation-simple ul li:hover, .navigation-simple ul li:hover a { }
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not seem to work correct in my browser, making it very hard to do anything in it. Any chance you could create a fiddle containing the bare essentials?